# 500 Internal Server Error in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend and encounter this error [500 Internal Server Error] when submitting a page that uploading files.
The error log file says as below.Does the email has to do with the Internal Server Error?

```
[23-Sep-2012 18:15:12] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()' in C:\Tools\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Tools\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 C:\Tools\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 C:\Projects\dcs_new\config_local.php(86): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 C:\Projects\dcs_new\functions.php(277): smail('level2@hartaleg...', 'DCS: Document c...', 'Title: Testing ...', 'From: TAN CHEN ...')
#4 C:\Projects\dcs_new\functions.php(284): email_users_obj('alert@hartalega...', Array, 'DCS: Document c...', 'Title: Testing ...', 'From: TAN CHEN ...')
 in C:\Tools\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail.php on line 137
```

Comment: does sendmail, postfix or SMTP mail setup on your server ?

Comment: you need to `try/catch` sending mail and react on such failure with ie. retry

Comment: how do I verify them? Can I verify from the phpinfo?

Comment: It turns out the it was due to the empty value for email. We found this mistake from the email server log.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your page/script attempts to send mail and tries to connect to an SMTP server running on `localhost:25`.

So, essentially, it's a configuration issue.

To get over the hump for local dev, you can set default transport to be `Zend_Mail_Transport_File` for the `development` environment.

In `application/configs/application.ini`:

```
[development : production]
resources.mail.transport.type = file
resources.mail.transport.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/mail"
```

Remember to create that `data/mail` directory and give the webserver permissions to write there.